# How do phonons and spinwaves interact?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, phonons, spin-models

What governs the coupling of acoustic phonons to transverse and longitudinal spinwaves? Is there a simple picture?

Comment: Do you mean like a simple quantum oscilator?

Comment: Can you be more precise? What do you mean by "what governs"? What do you know, what do you want to know?